# Auto sending Email

Tags: api, email

I would need something that would automatically run request to API at specified time, to retrieve list of email address and then sent those email at specified time. Any ideas how this could be done?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify your requirements? What language? What platform? Where are the email addresses stored? At present your question is vague to the point of being unanswerable.

Comment: Hi, I have no clue where to look at. That is why am I asking. email addressees are stored in SQL database, I can get list  by sending request to API

Comment: I do have Synology NAS, where I can schedule task (kick off script at any time).

Comment: My idea would be CURL www.example/strip.php at specified time. Would it be possible for PHP script to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the help of cron Jobs. Follow the following steps to set cron jobs.

**Go to your control panel search for Cron Jobs**

[image]

**In new window set you cron timing and path of your cron file.**

[image]

Now server will run your file automatically at set time.

If you have any query feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi, thanks for idea... I have just discovered that I can schedule scripts from my Synology NAS. Would you be able to help me a bit with how should such script look like? Simple script to send email with subject = subject to email@example.com